# How do I suppress output from a cat command that uses the os.system library in Python

Tags: python, bash

I have a Python 3 program that uses the os process to run the "cat" command.

This is the code fragment, it wirks great, but all the output ends up on the screeen.

os.system("cat *.txt | tee output.txt")

How can I suppress the output from appearing on the screen?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: You're getting output to the screen because you're explicitly running a command that produces output to the screen.  Why are you using `tee` here?  Just redirect the output to a file - `cat *.txt >output.txt`.

Comment: Using `os.system()` is not good form to start with. If you use the `subprocess` module instead, you get the option of `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL`, and in addition have the tools to avoid unnecessarily using a shell in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

#### Avoiding The Problem Altogether

`tee` writes to stdout. If you don't want to write to stdout, don't use `tee`:

```
os.system("cat -- *.txt >output.txt")
```

---

#### Redirecting Stdout Away

If you do want to use `tee`, you can explicitly redirect away its stdout:

```
os.system('cat -- *.txt | tee output.txt >/dev/null')
```

---

#### Using `subprocess.run` With `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL`

If you don't want to modify the shell command to add a redirection within it, `subprocess.run` gives you enough power to specify redirections to perform *before* starting a shell:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('cat -- *.txt | tee output.txt', shell=True,
               stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

---

#### Using `subprocess.run` Without `tee` Or A Shell

...but it's more efficient and less prone to security issues if you just don't use a shell at all:

```
import subprocess, glob

subprocess.run(['cat', '--'] + glob.glob('*.txt'),
               stdout=open('output.txt', 'w'))
```

---

#### Using `subprocess.run` With Tee, But Without A Shell

If you're up for not using a shell at all, but your real-world use case unconditionally includes some analogue to `tee`, the Python standard-library documentation describes how to accomplish this at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline, as demonstrated below:

```
import subprocess, glob
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat', '--'] + glob.glob('*.txt'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['tee', 'output.txt', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.communicate()
```

Answer (score -2):

You shall take care about the default shell used by os.system

Try to execute this to check the shell used in background:

```
python3 -c 'import os; os.system("ps $$")'
```

You can change your code a little bit to force the bash shell and redirect the output to /dev/null:

```
os.system('/bin/bash -c "cat *.txt | tee output.txt &>/dev/null"')
```

Note that regardless of the technique (you could use subprocess module) the point is the background shell and the output redirection.

Comment: `os.system('/bin/bash -c "..."')` is insanely silly. Why would you have `/bin/sh` start `bash` when there's no good reason to use bash-only functionality in the first place?

Comment: (the OP is only complaining about _output_ ending up on the screen, not errors; `>/dev/null` suffices; and if it didn't, then `>/dev/null 2>&1` would be fine).

Comment: `&>/dev/null` also isn't considered good form even in modern bash! See  https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Moreover, there's no reason to check what the shell invoked by `system()` is with `ps`; it's _always_ `/bin/sh` (on UNIXy platforms, which are the only ones where `ps $$` is expected to work in the first place).

Comment: My question to you is why to use cat and os.system then? Why? Of course you can avoid os.system and do your job differently with a true code without cat (if you are able to do it). But if the question is "why this simple instruction doesn't work" and "how can I make it working" the answer is in the usage of the underlying shell. Please add one more -1 now. But note that the question is focused on "os.system". My answer is appropriate as it is compliant with the desing pattern KISS: Keep It Simple Stupid.

Comment: Spawning an extra shell is hardly keeping it simple. Neither is telling the reader to use `ps` to check something that's a hardcoded constant, nor unnecessarily using nonportable/extended syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your "why use cat and os.system then?" question. One _shouldn't_ use `os.system()` in new code, which is why my answer includes an optional addendum describing several ways to avoid it. That's an addendum in order to be sure that we answer the OP's "real question", which is hard to identify since they didn't describe the constraints leading to their original code.

Comment: KISS...........

Comment: You keep saying "KISS" while defending an answer with a bunch of complexity unnecessary for answering the OP's question. As far as I can tell, "KISS" is a complete non sequitur. If you intend it to mean something to me, you'll need to spell out how and why in detail.

Comment: Note that the question was more bash-related than python-related. In this case the user is mixing two languages: bash scripting and python. If you really want to give a complete answer on python, I suggest you indicate how to replace the commands bash cat and tee with mechanisms for reading and writing files in python.

Comment: The other answer is community wiki; if you think there are things it should cover you're welcome to edit it yourself, or comment there.

Comment: As for _this_ answer, `os.system()` is _not_ guaranteed to start a bash interpreter. It _is_ guaranteed to start a POSIX-compliant shell interpreter. That's why I'm holding that `>/dev/null` is the right thing (optionally followed by `2>&1` if suppressing stderr is also desired). Starting a second interpreter that _is_ bash to use `&>/dev/null` is extra complexity, and the opposite of keeping it simple.

Comment: "As for this answer, os.system() is not guaranteed to start a bash interpreter" that's why I said to double check the interpreter and said how it can be done in bash. Note that the user tagged "bash". In my opinion it is a waste of time to talk about performance and complexity when dealing with a scripting language. If you want the best solution do it in C++ or Go... but I think the person who asked this question was looking for a fast way to fix his problem. That's why I do not think that my answer is "wrong" or "useless". But this is only your opinion. Please add one more -1.

Comment: ...anyway feel free to keep philosophizing. I leave this discussion as I already wasted too much time with you. But I think the purpose of this community it to share and help each other. Remember it.

Comment: I talked about complexity only to refute your claims about simplicity -- it's a topic you brought up first. If your want to say you're following KISS, that means you're _not _ doing anything needlessly complex.

Comment: As for the purpose of SO, our goal is to build the best possible Q&A knowledgebase. Sharing bad practice examples hurts achievement of that goal rather than helping it.